# .htaccess file doesn't respect server timezone

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

.htaccess file set as follows:

```
SetEnv TZ Pacific/Auckland
php_value date.timezone ‘Pacific/Auckland’
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ http://urlgoeshere.com/news/%{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}-%{TIME_HOUR}00-048.mp3 [R=301,L]
```

phpinfo.php shows the timezone is set to Pacific/Auckland, though the script rewrites according to Pacific Timezone. What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: For some reason PHP 5.4+ ignores Apache VirtualHost or .htaccess SetEnv TZ value, and just uses the php.ini setting. Super-annoying if you need to run multiple apps with different timezones on the same version of PHP, but I haven't found yet why the change was made.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a php value, for php interpreted scripts. Then you are rewriting with Apache. It is never using that php value, because it never executes a php script.

As far as I know, Apache uses the server timezone. See [this question on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/305086/changing-timezone-centos-apache-server) for more information. In short: Change `/etc/sysconfig/clock`, then restart the server.

To save yourself from headaches, I would recommend using UTC time for everything you do. It is a nightmare to have to deal with daylight saving and all the edge cases it brings, and it is even worse when you have an international audience and figure out that you have to suddenly translate between two variable timezones. UTC is always precise and constant and makes everything easier.

Comment: Apache may use server timezone but when running PHP it uses PHP's configured timezone in php.ini.

Comment: Or you know the `php_value` directive in the original question. I fail to see how it is relevant to this Q&A though...